# Docker image with dependencies pre-installed for CI

Tags: python, docker, continuous-integration

Common advice ([example](https://blog.sparksuite.com/7-ways-to-speed-up-gitlab-ci-cd-times-29f60aab69f9)) for carrying out CI is to use an image with pre-installed dependencies. Unfortunately for a n00b like me, the link in question doesn't go into further detail.

When I look for docker tutorials, it seems that usually teach you how to containerise an app rather than, say, Python with some pre-installed dependencies.

For example, if this is what my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like:

```
image: "python:3.7"

before_script:
  - python --version
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

stages:
  - Static Analysis

flake8:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
  - flake8 --max-line-length=120
```

how can I containerise Python with some pre-installed dependencies (here, the ones in `requirements.txt`), and how should I change the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, so that the CI process runs faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it faster I will recommend creating your custom Dockerfile based on `python:3.7` that has installed all the dependency during the build. So this will save your time and your job will do not need to install dependency during each job build.

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN  python --version

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy requirements.txt
COPY local-src/requirements.txt ./


# Install app dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Bundle app source
COPY src /app
```

You can read more about this practice [docker-python-pip-requirements](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/12/01/docker-python-pip-requirements/) and [write-effective-docker-files-with-python](https://medium.com/@Captain_Joannah/write-effective-docker-files-with-python-578ee26da69a)

Another option is to add git client in the Dockerfile and [pull code](https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/configure-a-docker-container-to-automatically-pull-from-github-using-oauth/) during creating the container.

Comment: Great, thanks! So then I can just replace the `image: "python:3.7"` part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with the new image I create from this Dockerfile, right? But how should the rest of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file change?

Comment: Yes exactly. You will be able to run this image anywhere. so this shoud be like you tag for example `image: python7:project-testing`

Comment: Thanks, works just as expected! Though for this particular use-case, I don't actually need `WORKDIR /app` and `COPY src /app`, right?

Comment: `copy` is used for to copy code from host where `workdir` is used for setting working direcotry.

Comment: Yeah, exactly - so seeing as here I'm just using a docker image to speed up the downloading dependencies part of the CI process, I don't need the code