# CI/CD tests involving pyspark - JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, continuous-integration

I am working on a project which uses pyspark, and would like to set up automated tests.

Here's what my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like:

```
image: "myimage:latest"

stages:
  - Tests

pytest:
  stage: Tests
  script:
  - pytest tests/.
```

I built the docker image `myimage` using a Dockerfile such as the following (see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57671668/10743932)):

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN  python --version

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy requirements.txt
COPY local-src/requirements.txt ./


# Install app dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Bundle app source
COPY src /app
```

However, when I run this, the gitlab CI job errors with the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py:95: in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
E   Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
------------------------------- Captured stderr --------------------------------
JAVA_HOME is not set
```

I understand that pyspark requires me to have JAVA8 or higher installed on my computer. I have this set up alright locally, but...what about during the CI process? How can I install Java so it works?

I have tried adding

```
RUN sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

to the Dockerfile which created the image, but got the error

```
/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found
```

.

How can I modify the Dockerfile so that tests using pyspark will work?

Comment: remove `sudo` from your commands

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution that worked for me: add

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install default-jdk -y
```

before

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It then all worked as expected with no further modifications needed!

### EDIT

To make this work, I've had to update my base image to python:3.7-stretch

Comment: This solution includes the one critical missing piece for me: apt-get install default-jdk.  

I saw 10 other posts with a bunch of jdk package names that never worked. Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk, openjdk-8-jre, and add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java is discontinued.  So many red herrings.

Answer (score 1):

Write in your .bash_profile:

export JAVA_HOME=(the home directory in your jdk i.e. /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/[yourjdk]/Contents/Home)